# Best way to avoid repeated code in add_user/sign up functionality

Tags: php, laravel-4

HI I'm implementing a site where I have two type of users admin/non-admin, where the admin can manage the users and add new one.
My problem Is that I have a sign up form where new users can sign up But when I want to create the "Add Users" functionality for admin users I notice that I'm repeating code, 2 sign up forms, 2 "store" functions..  I want to add a few fields to the user sign up admin form.
Which would be the best option ? Change the "store" UsersControllers method ?

Comment: I am not familiar with Laravel, but I'm fairly certain that you can set a variable unique to each i.e. $type = 1 or $type = 2 and then call the general form method using an if/else on the $type variable to differentiate between the two.

Comment: You don't want the controller to rely on a hidden input variable that could be manipulated by the client.

Never, ever trust the client

Comment: Not a hidden input that would be retarded. I meant pretty much as your answer. Call one method but use a variable (or ***something***) of some kind, Auth::check() as you put is a good one (+1'd the answer) to decide between user or administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the front end form in a seperate view (mymoduleview.blade.php)

`@include('mymoduleview')`

Then have the form action route to the same controller, but in the controller if

`Auth::check()` returns True it is a logged in user creating a user

`Auth::check()` returns False it is a guest signing up.

Comment: I like this solution, but who will be the controller that will have the "store" function UsersController or AdminController ?? I think UsersController ?

Comment: You can have it route to UsersController where the logic is stored, but if you really want to be technical about it then if Auth::check() passes call a function in AdminController which handles the additional logic if an admin is creating the account. :) Hope this helps.